# Why does my ssh login include what looks like a promotion for a TechRepublic article?

Tags: ssh, login, bashrc

When I ssh into my Ubuntu box I see the output below. I was surprised to see the quote and the link to the TechRepublic article.

Is that an advertisement? Anyone know where that is coming from? Is there any way to remove that?

Thanks,
Ben

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-37-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Sun 21 Jun 2020 10:06:54 PM PDT

  System load:  0.05                Processes:                249
  Usage of /:   43.6% of 227.74GB   Users logged in:          0
  Memory usage: 8%                  IPv4 address for enp0s25: <redacted>
  Swap usage:   0%                  IPv4 address for wlp2s0:  <redacted>
  Temperature:  56.0 C

 * "If you've been waiting for the perfect Kubernetes dev solution for
   macOS, the wait is over. Learn how to install Microk8s on macOS."

   https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-microk8s-on-macos/

0 updates can be installed immediately.
0 of these updates are security updates.
```

Comment: Yeah, I use Linux and very irritating for me an ad about macOS in full-linux env.

Comment: This got me fuming.  Back to Debian.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this file:

```
/etc/pam.d/sshd
```

Comment out the following 2 lines:

```
# session    optional     pam_motd.so motd=/run/motd.dynamic
# session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
```

This should remove the MOTD.

Comment: Thanks. That removes all messages at login (except for the last login date/time). I could have lived with the other stuff, but the ad seemed a little much.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach is to specify `ENABLED=0` in the config file `/etc/default/motd-news`. This may be preferred, based on a review of `/etc/update-motd.d/50-motd-news`:

```
$ grep -A5 Source /etc/update-motd.d/50-motd-news
# Source the local configuration
[ -r /etc/default/motd-news ] && . /etc/default/motd-news

# Exit immediately, unless we're enabled
# This makes this script very easy to disable in /etc/default/motd-news configuration
[ "$ENABLED" = "1" ] || exit 0
```

You can update `/etc/default/motd-news` in your editor of choice, or use sed or perl. Note that root privileges are required:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/ENABLED=1/ENABLED=0/' /etc/default/motd-news
```

Comment: This is also the preferred way in ["What exactly is being sent to Ubuntu in the MOTD?"](https://ma.ttias.be/what-exactly-being-sent-ubuntu-motd/)

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  Removes only the "news" portion and leaves the semi-useful rest of it.

Answer (score 3):

The link to the TechRepublic article is coming from the output of this script, which is executed for each login:

```
/etc/update-motd.d/50-motd-news
```

You can disable just that script by removing execution permissions:

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/update-motd.d/50-motd-news
```